# Part of chain link broken

Tags: chain

I just got this bike from a neighbor and I saw that one of the chain links is broken on one side but not the other. What's the cheapest way to fix this situation?

The bike is a Next Xelite that I'm looking to upgrade to an E-bike.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you do not invest money in this bicycle. It is a true BSO (Bicycle Shaped Object), and is not designed to be ridden much farther than around the block a few times. There may be many more problems with it than just the chain.

Comment: May not be a good idea for ebike when you realise the weight of ebike kit.

Comment: You need either a new chain or several links taken from an old chain.  And a chain tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the side plates of the chain is falling off, you need a new chain.

Chains are relatively cheap, and get one with a master link so you don't even need a special tool.

It may be possible to push it back on, but it'll fall off again real quick, probably taking the other side with it.  This is false economy.  You should also start a maintenance log of when various tasks were done, same as a car logbook.  Chains should be replaced periodically, before they chew into the cassette.

Comment: I suppose... if your chain was sufficiently long alredy, that you could knock off the dead outer link and whichever inner link shares the same pin.  Then rejoin the chain with a chain tool.   However this will leave the chain shorter, making certain gear combinations harder or impossible to reach.   Not recommended, and a chain tool would be strongly advised.  But its the cheapest answer as requested.... just not a good answer.

Comment: Then how many links total in the NEXT PX 6.0 XelitE Bicycle? I've seen different sizes but I don't want one too small or too big. But on the other hand, I can use a chain breaker to make the longer chain the same size. Thanks for giving me an idea guys.

Comment: You can read how to size a chain here: www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing

Comment: Thanks Batman, that helps a lot. I've put it into my favorites.

Comment: Wrong!!  You **do** need a "special tool" (chain breaker) to cut the chain to the proper length before installing.  And chains should be replaced when they measure "stretched".  This measurement can be done with a ruler, but using an inexpensive stretch gauge is much simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Take broken link out (actually, two links, otherwise it won't fit back) and rivet the chain back. It is preferred to use repair pin when assembling the chain back (they're cheap, and MUCH easier to fit in). But if you don't have one, make sure when you taking out the pin not to push it all the way out of the chain, so it stays in the link - later it will be easier to push it back.

Chain will become shorter but still work. Maybe 3-1 combination won't work but it isn't normally used anyway.

Also, if the chain is old and worn, just throw it away and buy a new one Use chain wear measuring tool, or base you decision on the amount of riding, 2000 km will be a good point to replace. DON'T ride on the worn chain, it will chew the gears quickly.

Comment: @Móż, are you talking about me or Dmitriy? I have already planned on putting the bike in the shop next month when I get paid so I won't get frustrated and give up. I'm going to get it done by a professional with the whole works done to it.